# How do I retrieve only the needed line from terminal output?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to get only let's say third line of `df -h` output.

What kind of command should I use?

Comment: **Note for the future:** this question is very very basic. It is typically encouraged to show certain effort and what you've tried before asking.

Comment: While it may be legit to get the 3rd line of a file with a presumed static format, that is different than the 3rd line of a diagnostic program with output that various depending on the state of the system. For instance mounting a new drive/partition alphabetically before your current 3rd line blows it. Thus @Random832's answer below is the best.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This will output the 3rd line, regardless of content.

```
df -h | sed -n 3p
```

Comment: +1 for smallest answer: `df -h|sed -n 3p`.

Answer (score 16):

The `df` command actually accepts an argument identifying the filesystem you want. So you could use, for example, `df /home` or `df /dev/sda3`.

If you intend to parse the output for a script, you'll want to use `df -P` to guarantee it never wraps to multiple lines. So, for example, you could use `df -Ph /home | tail -n +2` (but if you're parsing output for a script, be aware of the possibility of filenames with spaces in them)

Comment: That's it! Instead of parsing the output, use the command to provide _just_ what you want.

Comment: But the OP said he wanted line 3. `df /home` provides a header. You're interpreting the user's purpose. You may be right. You may be wrong, who knows?

Comment: @MikeS A dozen other answers already covered getting line 3 with no context. I provided additional information so that the OP will have it if it is useful for him. And `tail -n +2` removes the header.

Answer (score 14):

You can use a combination of `head` and `tail`:

```
df -h | head -3 | tail -1
```

Or

```
df -h | tail -n +3 | head -1
```

But note that, `df` allows to filter the output from the options of `df` itself, you should look at those first before using any external command.

Check `man df`.

Comment: +1 for mention that df can filter specific entries

Comment: Indeed, it's almost always better to filter the data itself before piping to external programs.

Answer (score 10):

Awk is text processing tool, so it's appropriate for this task

```
df -h | awk 'NR == 3'
```

Answer (score 6):

I assume you're not necessarily looking for the third line, but for the line that either mentions a specific disk (e.g. `/dev/sda3`) or a specific mount point (e.g. `/home`).

So instead of just displaying the third line, which is insecure because the output order might change and you might get a different result, you can filter the output by content and show only the lines that match a specific pattern or contain a keyword.

Your tool for this is `grep`.

For example if you want the line about device `/dev/sda3`, you type:

```
df -h | grep '/dev/sda3'
```

If you want the line mentioning your home directory as mount point, use:

```
df -h | grep '/home'
```

Comment: Or `df -h /dev/sda3` or `df -h /home` (the latter works even if it's not a mount point).

Answer (score 6):

You could also use `perl`:

```
df -h | perl -ne 'print if $.==3'
```

The `$.` is the current line number, so you could print the Nth line with `perl -ne 'print if $.==N'`.

Comment: This is why Perl is still relevant in my view. It combines sed and awk with a structured programming language that (while many will say is really really ugly [and I might agree]) is at least consistent and very useful for these short one-liners. Thanks terdon. This is almost as succinct as the sed example, if a bit more verbose.

Comment: @MikeS glad to help. As a Perl hacker, however, I must point out that Perl code is only as ugly as you make it. Good programmers can write beautiful code in Perl, it's just that the langauge doesn't force you to and it is easy not to.

Answer (score 2):

My first idea would be a head-tail-construct.

Example:

```
df -h | head -3 | tail -1
```

`head -3` causes the output to stop after three lines and `tail -1` will output only the last line.

Alternatively, if you know, how the output will look like, you could also use `grep` to find lines containing a certain string.